# How to get(extract) Quill editor icon in .jpg/.png format? (they only have SVG format)

Tags: javascript, svg, quill

#### 1. This is Quill editor

https://github.com/quilljs/quill

### 2. I want get these icon(I quote in red box) in .jpg/.png

[image]

Now they are `.svg` format, and locate in this directory
https://github.com/quilljs/quill/tree/develop/assets/icons

### 3. I already try couple way, so far no success.

These svg format are not self-contain.
I can't just grab these .svg file and convert them to .jpg easily (like use online tool)
the svg style are written in CSS
[image] 
this screenshot are taken in Quill Playground: https://codepen.io/quill/pen/KzZqZx

### 4. I already ask this in Quill Github issue

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2281
but these kind of not bug-relate issue are not welcome there.

### 5. Question: How to get quill editor icon in .jpg/.png format?

Thank you very much!

### 6. Last thing

you may ask why I want jpg/png format?

because in certain old browser that I have to support (360 browser)
svg can not reader, .svg would become blank.
I have to use image

Comment: There are plenty of [online converters](https://ezgif.com/svg-to-png) are they not suitable for you?

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for reply! I am aware of these online converter(svg->jpg etc). it's not a simple convert problem. I tried. the .svg they provide in assets/ folder are not self-contain, style are in CSS file. they are separated. that what make it difficult to extract.

Comment: Of course you can just extract the SVG string into separate files and convert them with any SVG editor like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), but you can also get the images from [materialdesignicons.com](https://materialdesignicons.com/) in any format you need, they look nearly the same.

Comment: Commit [4723921](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/tree/4723921b66b33bd41609df9e30be0756c1c0f5c2) is the last one that has the SVGs as self-contained files without stylesheet dependencies.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I don't know I can do that. Thanks for telling me!